# data access approach for using sqlite in C# VS2008 project?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2008, sqlite, data-access-layer

I've got Sqlite working in a basic sense for my C# project in Visual Studio 2008 via use of the ADO.net Sqlite wrapper from http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/.

Question - For a C# winforms newbie what VS2008 data access layer approach would you recommend I look to use for my winforms app, as I need to write/read data from the sqlite database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ works fine with Entity Framework.  VS2010 doesn't seem to create the correct SQL for a "create DB from model" approach, however the "create Model from DB" approach works fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an ORM like Subsonic? [SubsonicProject.com](http://www.subsonicproject.com)

Comment: I was thinking of one of the Microsoft approaches that is integrated with VS2008...(but I'm new to .net)...is there not a way in VS2008 to automatically create the C# wrappers to access the data in the database?

Comment: You mean like using Linq? Check out this related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250071/linq-with-sqlite-linqtosql

Comment: yes - thanks, this is the kind of thing I had in mind - does this mean there is no Microsoft out of the box Linq To Sql for sqlite?

Comment: what about Entity Framework for example too? if there were sqlite support would this be any easier way to get a basic layer in place so I could work in the C# object world and not have to type SQL for my sqlite database?

Comment: Entity Framework is supported by the SQLite ADO provider.
There are a few issues with it that can be worked around.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936804/sqlite-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this lightweight SQLite wrapper, which has reflection-based ORM features, and some easy-to-use Linq support: http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/

It links directly to the released SQLite library, and has no other dependencies.